# Weird onchange event in Chrome with autofill fields and Stripe embed

Tags: google-chrome, knockout.js, stripe-payments, onchange, autofill

We have a weird issue happening in Chrome autofill where if I autofill the forms in the video link it causes an onchange event on my Type dropdown that is using knockout.js and sends an undefined value.

There isn't anything special on the form fields like any type of events.  When I autofill and then click with the Stripe embed you can see it clears it.  I can wait about 2 seconds after autofilling, and it doesn't.  I have debugged the observable subscription and it only says it originated from a jquery onchange event.

This does not happen in Edge and does not happen if I type out the values.

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/21279150?key=df18226d86c4443f57f56cd9b4cb37d3

**Form Html**

```
<div class="col">
        <h2>Billing Contact</h2>
        <div class="form-row form-group">
    <label for="Payment_Organization">Organization</label>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-auto">
        <input id="Payment_Organization" maxlength="100" name="Payment.Organization" type="text" value="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row form-group">
    <label class="required" for="Payment_FirstName">First Name</label>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-auto">
        <input class="billing-first-name" id="Payment_FirstName" maxlength="100" name="Payment.FirstName" type="text" value="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row form-group">
    <label class="required" for="Payment_LastName">Last Name</label>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-auto">
        <input class="billing-last-name" id="Payment_LastName" maxlength="100" name="Payment.LastName" type="text" value="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row form-group">
    <label class="required" for="Payment_Email">Email</label>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-auto">
        <input class="billing-email" id="Payment_Email" maxlength="100" name="Payment.Email" type="text" value="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row form-group">
    <label class="required" for="Payment_Phone">Phone</label>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-auto">
        <input class="billing-phone" id="Payment_Phone" maxlength="25" name="Payment.Phone" type="text" value="">
    </div>
</div>

    </div>
```